# Rasterizing vector file in EPSG:4326 using GDAL/OGR in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, rasterization, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to rasterize the vector file in Python.

I used this code:

```
gdal.Grid("trial2.tif", "merged2018-19.gpkg", zfield="h_li", algorithm="nearest")
```

(the crs of vector data is in EPSG:4326 )

On plotting the vector file in Jupyter it showed the coordinates X axis: 74 to 78 (longitude value) Y axis: 35 to 38 (latitude value)
After rasterizing using this code X Axis: 0 to 250 Y Axis: 250 to 0

i.e. its CRS value is lost (I guess)

It created a raster file but with pixel resolution (0.015625 degree, 0.01171875 degree) which is quite large enough. How can I regulate the pixel size here?